# Dataframe scatterplot vs Matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a scatter plot to view the relationship between my data, but for some reason my matplotlib plot is really ugly and honestly doesn't even make sense (from what I can tell, it looks like there are points past the X and y max in the scatterplot.

Here is what it looks like when I plot it using dataframe's plot. 
[image: dataframe scatterplot]

Now, this is what it looks like when I plot it with matplotlib. As you can see from the first plot, the x value's max is about 9 while the y value max is 50 (this is also confirmed when I do a x.describe(), y.describe()).

[image: matlibplot scatterplot]

Here is the code I used to get to this point:

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/housing/housing.data', header = None, sep='\s+')
data.columns = ['CRIM','ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 
'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX','PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']

X = data[['RM']]
y = data[['MEDV']]

data.plot(kind='scatter', x='RM', y='MEDV')
xScale = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
yScale = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60]
plt.xticks(xScale)
plt.yticks(yScale)
plt.xlabel("Avg Num Rooms")
plt.ylabel("Avg Price (in 1000s)")
plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.show()
```

I'm new to matplotlib so it's possible I'm using the ticks wrong. But when I set `xlim` and `ylim` to their appropriate values, it also seems like I only see a few data points with matplotlib.

This is the plot using matlibplt but without any scaling (removing the xticks and yticks code)

[image: matlibplt no scaling]

Comment: What do you get from default matplotlib, without the `plt.xticks` and `plt.yticks` lines? Also, it would be really helpful if you could post code as formatted text instead of images.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to convert your data to numbers. If the data is strings the result is expected. However, always provide [mcve] when asking a question here. Always! It's not like people here are magicians that can know what's wrong with a code without seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, good point I edited to include my code and the plot without plt.xticks and plt.yticks. Good point, I'll check that. I'm not that familiar with Python's datastructures so I'm not clear the difference between an array of numbers and how X and y are being stored. You were right. Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest